# Is there any way to repair an item damaged by a Rust Monster?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, equipment

The Rust Monster (MM p.262) can inflict a "permanent and cumulative -1 penalty" to the damage of weapons, or to the AC of armor or shields.

Is there any way to repair this damage?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### The RAW are silent on this exact point

So, firstly if you want a specific written rule on how to repair rust-monster-damaged weapons and armor, you're not going to find them in the currently published rulebooks.

### 'Permanent'

The key word here is 'permanent' which can have two interpretations, again not specified by the RAW.

1. not temporary (ie will not *automatically* recover)
2. irrevocable (ie can never be recovered)

### Mundane repair

If you take 'permanent' to mean 1, someone with Smith's tools proficiency and access to a forge (and some extra metal) could repair the armor and shields. After all, the weapons are not destroyed until they are at -5, and armor until it reaches AC 10, so there must be some salvageable metal under the rust.

### Magic repair

If you take it to mean 2, all is still not lost. Lesser magics like the Mending cantrip won't cut it, as they are only meant for repairing breaks and tears, but if the Wish spell can repair Daern's Instant Fortress (DMG 161), then a few rusty swords shouldn't be a problem.

### But why bother?

But as the Rust Monster only damages *nonmagical weapons and armor* it seems like in most cases it would be less trouble to buy some new gear...

Answer (score 5):

Well we could take this into the real world to answer.

A fine layer of rust will have no appreciable affect on a sword or armor's effectiveness, though it could make joints stiff.

However, if the amount of rust is enough to appreciably reduce the effectiveness of the item, then it means an appreciable amount of material has been lost.

You can't just add another layer of forged or smithed material to a sword or shield to restore it. You would effectively have to recycle the item for its material and smith a new item from the reclaimed metal.

Comment: Then I think you missed the point of my answer. Other than light oxidation, if something has rusted enough to reduce its efdectiveness as a sword or shield or piece of armor, it's lost too much material to be _maintained_ back into shape. That's why the damage is _permanent_ per the MM.

Comment: Do not answer in comments, even on someone else's answer.

Comment: In real world forging, is reforging a rusty metal item any faster or easier or does it take any less costly material than just starting from scratch?

Comment: @Feygon in reforging you would effectively destroy the item and forge something new with the material. You don't restore this way. However, usually with steel, you do not recycle the metal, you either start with a fresh raw material (because those impurities are important to the process), or you at least add some new raw material to the recycled so you aren't dealing with too pure a metal.